# Is it possible to define custom allocators for perforce (p4api)?

Tags: c++, perforce

In the [Perforce c++ api](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api/Content/P4API/Home-p4api.html) is it possible to provide a custom allocator so that a function like [StrBuf::Alloc()](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api/Content/P4API/strbuf.alloc.html) uses the functions I provide rather than regular old new/delete or malloc/free?

This is primarily to maintain control over how memory is used by my program, but also to provide metrics and whatnot so that I can see how memory is used. If it doesn't go through my system then it's untracked and unaccounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create your own StrPtr subclass for your own use, but you can't change memory allocation inside the P4 client library.

Enabling debugging inside the heap itself might provide you with the type of analysis you're looking for: https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-visual-studio/debug-heap-issues-using-full-page-heap